# Multilevel sorting in Realm: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field name does not exist

Tags: android, realm

I have objects A, B, C in my Realm. And structure is like this:

```
public class A extends RealmObject {
    ...
    private B b;
    //all setters/getters implemented
}

public class B extends RealmObject {
    ...
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private RealmList<C> cs;
    //all setter/getters implemented
}

public class C extends RealmObject {
    ...
    private int priority;
    //all setter/getters implemented
}
```

I wish to query ***A*** objects and sort on ***priority*** in ***C*** class and some other members, so I do something like this:

```
String[] sortingFields = new String[] {
            "b.cs.priority",...
            //other fields
    };
    boolean[] sortingOrders = new boolean[] {
            RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING,
            ...
            //respective sorting orders
    };

return realm
            .where(A.class)
            .equalTo("B.id", id)
            .findAllSorted(sortingFields, sortingOrders);
```

When I try it, I get following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field name 'b.cs.priority' does not exist.
```

Can someone please help and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Best,
Deveti

Comment: Sorting using child object properties is not supported by Realm right now. However, the exception message is confusing. An issue is created to track that https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2034 . In you example, one thing is not clear that `cs` is a list, how do you want to sort A with members of List 's property? There could be lots of members in cs. If it is a sing object, one workaround could be store/update the priority in A as well just for sorting.